# Proof for equivalence of two regular expressions

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I have to show via equivalence transformation, that these two regular expressions are equivalent:

$$(ab+b^*a^*) = (a+b^*)(a^*+b)$$

Can someone give me a hint how to show this? I am only allowed to use these equivalences:

$$
R+S = S+R \\
(R+S)+T = R+(S+T) \\
(R S) T = R (S T) \\
\emptyset + R = R + \emptyset = R \\
\varepsilon R = R \varepsilon = R \\
\emptyset R = R \emptyset = \emptyset \\
R (S + T) = RS + RT \\
(S + T)R = SR + TR \\
R + R = R\\
(R^*)^* = R^* \\
(\varepsilon + R)^* = R^* \\
\emptyset^* = \varepsilon \\
\varepsilon^* = \varepsilon \\
(\varepsilon + R)R^* = R^*(\varepsilon + R) = R^*\\
RR^* = R^*R \\
R^* + R = R^* \\
\varepsilon + RR^* = R^*
$$

[My best attempt so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eua7i.png)

Comment: I added a picture of my best try so far. This is also, where I'm stuck.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't read it.  You ought to type it.

Comment: Looks good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for any $R$,

$$R^*+\epsilon=\epsilon+(\epsilon+R)R^*=\epsilon+\epsilon R^*+RR^*=\epsilon+R^*+RR^*=R^*+(\epsilon+RR^*)=R^*+R^*=R^*$$

So

$$b^*a^*=(b^*+\epsilon)a^*=b^*a^*+\epsilon a^*=b^*a^*+a^*=b^*a^*+(\epsilon+a)a^*=b^*a^*+\epsilon a^*+aa^*=(b^*+\epsilon)a^*+aa^*=b^*a^*+aa^*$$

Likewise

$$b^*a^*=b^*(a^*+\epsilon)=b^*a^*+b^*\epsilon=b^*a^*+b^*=b^*a^*+(\epsilon+b)b^*=b^*a^*+\epsilon b^*+bb^*\\=b^*a^*+b^*\epsilon+b^*b=b^*(a^*+\epsilon)+b^*b=b^*a^*+b^*b$$

So that $b^*a^*=b^*a^*+aa^*+b^*b$.

Now

$$(a+b^*)(a^*+b)=(a+b^*)a^*+(a+b^*)b=aa^*+b^*a^*+ab+b^*b=ab+b^*a^*$$

Comment: Wow, this is a very fast and beautiful solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: At the beginning of the second equation, you are using $b^*=b^*+\epsilon$. Since this is not among the given equivalences, you should probably provide a derivation. A possible one is as follows: $R^*+\epsilon=RR^*+\epsilon+\epsilon = RR^*+\epsilon=R^*$.

Comment: @Federico See the first line. Admittedly not the shortest way.

Comment: Oh, well, yeah... Sorry I didn't see it :D

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT to clarify my answer.** The core of the solution is highlighted in yellow.

I introduce the following *useful* concept, that permits to better reason about regular expressions.

**Definition.** I write $R\subset S$ if there exists $T$ such that $R+T=S$.

**Lemma.** If $R\subset S$, then $R+S=S$.

*Proof.* $R+S = R + (R+T) = (R+R)+T = R+T=S$. □

> Now, back to your problem. We have
>   $$
> (a+b^*)(b+a^*)
> = ab + aa^* + b^*b + b^*a^* ,
> $$
>   but $aa^*\subset b^*a^*$ and $b^*b\subset b^*a^*$, so
>   $$
> (a+b^*)(b+a^*)
> = ab + b^*a^* .
> $$

You may ask, why is $aa^*\subset b^*a^*?$ Well, that's easy 'cause
$$
b^*a^* = (\epsilon+b^*)(\epsilon+a)a^* = aa^* + \text{other terms}.
$$

---

For the nitpickers.
In the last formula, we used also $b^*=b^*+\epsilon$ at the beginning. Since this is not among the given equivalences, a possible derivation is as follows: $R^*+\epsilon=RR^*+\epsilon+\epsilon = RR^*+\epsilon=R^*$.

Otherwise, using our useful subset concept, notice that $\epsilon\subset R^*$, because $R^*=\epsilon+RR^*$; but then our lemma says $R^*+\epsilon=R^*$.

---

To conclude, I urge you to try the same exercise with a more complicate regular expression and see whether this *subset* thing does indeed simplify the derivations or not.

Just compare my short formulas with those of the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you prove the fact that you are using?

Comment: Well, $R\subset S$ means that $S=R+T$ for some $T$, but then in particular $R+S=R+R+T=R+T=S$

Comment: I mean, it's quite obvious if you think that $R$ is the set of matched strings and $+$ is the set union: $R\subset S \implies R\cup S=S$

Comment: The question is how to use the equivalences given in the question and I am afraid your answer does not give any proof.

Comment: You might then ask why $aa^*\subset b^*a^*$, but that is also clear, as $b^*a^* = (b^*+\epsilon)(a+\epsilon)a^*=(b^*+\epsilon)(aa^*+a^*)=aa^*+\mathrm{others}$

Comment: @J.-E.Pin It does. I just added one (_useful_) concept to the list: being a subset